# Calling a Fortran routine from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In 2009, I wrote a little application that involved calling a Fortran DLL (contents unavailable) into a VB.NET application. It worked. However, I now need to revisit the code and have found the the VB.NET application won't run from the original source code if it is compiled in Visual Studio Community 2017.

The arguments of the Fortran dll are a combination of arrays of integers, reals and chars:

```
SV is a string (array of Fortran characters?)
IV is an array of Fortran integers
RV is an array of Fortran reals
```

Within the VB code, I have used:

```
Dim IV(1279) As Integer
Dim RV(15999) As Single
Dim IERR As Integer
Dim SV As New String(" ", 5120)
Dim FileDir As New String(" ", 64)

Call FORT_SUB(SV, 5120, IV(1), RV(1), IERR)
```

The resulting EXE crashes at the Call line. I can only think the syntax requirements must have changed slightly and that I now need to make the Fortran call slightly differently...

Comment: `crashes at the Call line` is not very descriptive.  When you run the code in debugger, what was exception message?

Comment: Are both program and dll compiled under the same processor architecture? e.g. 64 bit or 32 bit? Try recompiling your program to match the dll.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Could not load file or assembly 'VBNET.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. occurred

Answer (score 1):

My target platform was wrong. The old DLL was x86 architecture but my VB2017 compiler defaulted to x64. I changed that and my old code now compiles and runs. Happy days.

Comment: Bingo! Glad to have helped ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The .Net version in your new VS2017 is probably newer than your original code. I would change the .Net version to what CLR version you were using then; probably .Net 3.5. Then you need to import your DLL. Ensure that when you add your reference to your DLL you can inspect in your object browser. Now I am also assuming that your DLL is not managed code meaning code not written in .Net. I would check these things first and then move forward from there.